# Aframe asset loading for asset on google cloud bucket renders a black plane instead of an image

Tags: reactjs, aframe

This problem only occurs on iOS. I am attempting to get image assets from a cloud bucket. Below is an example.

```
          <Entity primitive="a-assets">
            <img id="DohenySkybox" src={`${GOOGLE_CLOUD_BUCKET_STATIC}/Doheny.jpg`} crossOrigin="Anonymous" />
          <Entity/>
          <Entity primitive="a-sky" id="skybox" src="#DohenySkybox"></Entity>
```

However, if I load it via local assets, it works fine. I am only loading it from the cloud so that the download speed is quicker. I am using React.js if that makes any difference.

Comment: Without a link to runnable code people can look at and suggest solutions is hard to help. Glitch is a good option https://glitch.com/~aframe

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would solve the problem but you could try defining the source inline like:

`` <Entity primitive="a-sky" id="skybox" src={`${GOOGLE_CLOUD_BUCKET_STATIC}/Doheny.jpg`}></Entity> ``

I believe all this does is makes it so the scene doesn't wait for the sky to load before loading itself...in other words the sky can load after the scene loads. Maybe the image loading is timing out for the asset while the scene is loading? Give it a try.